# Presto comparing two dates and add condition

Tags: sql, presto, trino

For any given date I would like to add a condition if `date_` > `purchase date`
by 12 months add **1** else **0**.

example table

```
customer_id   date_         purchase_date
34555        2019-01-01    2017-02-01
24252        2019-01-01    2018-02-10
96477        2019-01-01    2017-02-18
```

desired output table

```
customer_id   date_         purchase_date purchase_date_older_than_12_months
34555        2019-01-01    2017-02-01    1
24252        2019-01-01    2018-02-10    0
96477        2019-01-01    2018-02-18    1
```

This is what I've tried so far. I know that I should be using datediff but not exactly sure how to do it

```
,CASE WHEN date_ > purchase_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS purchase_date_older_than_12_months
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(CASE WHEN date_ > DATE_ADD('month', 12, purchase_date)
      THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END) AS purchase_date_older_than_12_months
```

Comment: I get the following error: ' Column 'month' cannot be resolved'

Comment: @user12625679 . . . I have no idea why they would essentially borrow a function from SQL Server and then change the syntax.  The first argument needs to be a string.  I fixed the answer.